# SSH2 PHP Extension

Tags: php, ssh, centos, pecl, libssh2

I have been trying for a while to get the SSH 2 extension for php installed on my CentOS 5.6 x64 server. I started the server from scratch and here are the steps I have taken

1. install and configure APF
2. install apache
3. install php
4. install mysql
5. add epel repository
6. install php-pear so I can use pecl
7. run yum install libssh2-devel
8. run pecl install ssh2-beta
9. echo extension=ssh2.so>>/etc/php.ini
   (There were a few extra things in there such as installing phpMyadmin and wordpress)

After this I run php -m to see the php modules and ssh2 is not listed. I have been searching forever for tutorials and have found a few but from what I can see I have done everything correctly. Can anyone see where I am going wrong. I can provide any config files you may need. Also I have hear about phpseclib and was wondering if this would be an easier/better route? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know CeentOS, but you only have one PHP.ini right? Not one for CLI & one for Apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could maybe try [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), instead.  eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $sftp->pwd() . "\r\n";
$sftp->put('filename.ext', 'hello, world!');
print_r($sftp->nlist());
?>
```

Comment: I think this is going to be what I am going to use. Have you used this library before? Specifically the SSH functions?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure /etc/php.ini is actually used. check php --info output to see the used ini file(s)

At least on debian the path would be /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Comment: I checked and this is the used however from what I have found there is a patch that must be done for the module to work with php 5.3.* which I am using.

Comment: Can you please provide me that patch. I am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's no difference, but if not already like this, try:

```
extension="ssh2.so"
```